# Migrating a Virtual Drive (File Share) from Windows Server 2008 to 2016

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share, migration, file-sharing

We have this legacy file server running on Windows Server 2008 Enterprise as a VM on VMWare esxi host. The storage drive is a separate VM disk attached to the OS VM.

We want to migrate to Windows Server 2016.

Is it possible to detach the storage disk from the 2008 VM and re-attach it to another VM running Windows Server 2016 and do some minimal reconfiguration to get the shares up and running again?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can re-attach disk to another VM which is running Windows 2016 without any issues. But you need to configure a File Server which will be using your disk for file shares, completely reconfigure the shares and permissions. OR you can follow guidance from Microsoft about the migration from 2008 to the 2012R2 (which will work with 2016 as well) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn479292(v=ws.11)"

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes - I'm aware that I'll have to reconfigure the new server with the File Server role. The share permissions are based on objects in Active Directory - so I'm hoping there's an easy way to migrate them. The primary reason behind "moving" the disk is that I don't have enough space on the SAN.